# Resample Dataframe Monthly and store the count for each month in new Dataframe with columns as Date and Count

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe, plot

I want to sample my Dataframe with the date as an index to monthly data and count the instances for each month and then store it in a new dataframe.

Data:

```
Date        Title
2001-05-22    A
2001-05-28    B
2001-06-13    C
2001-06-14    D
2001-06-15    E
2001-07-15    F
2001-07-13    G
2001-07-16    H
2001-07-17    I
    .         .
    .         .
    .         .
2001-12-01    Y 
2001-12-31    Z
```

So I want the ouput should be like:
New Dataframe with columns

```
Date        Count
2001-05-31    2
2001-06-30    3
2001-07-31    4
2001-08-30    1
     .        .
     .        .
```

And after that, plot the data as any graph(bar or which ever looks good for such data) with date as x-axis. 

**Note:** The data is for a long-range period(2001-2017) so x-axis shouldn't get overlap.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) after your you set `Date` to datetime format:

Starting from your dataframe:

```
>>> df
         Date Title
0  2001-05-22     A
1  2001-05-28     B
2  2001-06-13     C
3  2001-06-14     D
4  2001-06-15     E
5  2001-07-15     F
6  2001-07-13     G
7  2001-07-16     H
8  2001-07-17     I
9  2001-12-01     Y
10 2001-12-31     Z
```

Set to datetime and `groupby` month:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='m')).count()
```

Output:

```
            Title
Date             
2001-05-31      2
2001-06-30      3
2001-07-31      4
2001-08-31      0
2001-09-30      0
2001-10-31      0
2001-11-30      0
2001-12-31      2
```

To plot, you can use this as a skeleton (I don't really know what you're looking for in a plot):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
gb = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='m')).count()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.bar(gb.index, gb.Title)
plt.ylabel('count')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: And do know about plotting?

Answer (score 1):

You said that your DataFrame has date as an index, I would use resample in that case

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.resample('M').count()



            Title
Date    
2001-05-31  2
2001-06-30  3
2001-07-31  4
2001-08-31  0
2001-09-30  0
2001-10-31  0
2001-11-30  0
2001-12-31  2
```

To create a plot, use pandas plot

```
df.resample('M').count().plot()
```

[image]

Comment: And do know about plotting?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific, what kind of plot?

Comment: After resampling the data I need to plot it means I want to represent it that for each month this much was the count. I didn't get which graph to use and how should I plot it with this data.